# Calculating the variance of an estimator (unclear on one step)

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

[image]

How can you go from $4V(\bar X)$ to $\displaystyle \frac{4}{n}V(X_1)$? I understand the rest of the steps...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed (this is used explicitly in equality 3 and 4) we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X})&=\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}(X_i)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}n\mathrm{Var}(X_1)=\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Var}(X_1).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Follow up question: How can you change the Xi to X1? Could you have just as easily have picked X2 or Xn? What's the deal?

Comment: Yes, this is because $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (presumably) are identically distributed. In particular, $\mathrm{Var}(X_1)=\cdots=\mathrm{Var}(X_n)$.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense, thanks!